# Unable to start guidewire PC server from tomcat

Tags: guidewire, gosu

We have been trying to start the policycenter server from tomcat. The server is getting started even though it throws exception with the message "PolicyCenter unable to start" in the logs. Please find the log details below.

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.osgi.service.log.LogLevel"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
                            at java.lang.ClassLoader.checkCerts(ClassLoader.java:1150) ~[?:?]
                            at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(ClassLoader.java:905) ~[?:?]
                            at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1014) ~[?:?]
                            at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174) ~[?:?]
                            at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2489) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.63]
                            at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:875) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.63]
                            at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1376) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.63]
                            at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1220) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.63]
                            at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.log.EquinoxLogServices.<init>(EquinoxLogServices.java:90) ~[org.eclipse.osgi-3.13.300.jar:?]
                            at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainer.<init>(EquinoxContainer.java:68) ~[org.eclipse.osgi-3.13.300.jar:?]
                            at org.eclipse.osgi.launch.Equinox.<init>(Equinox.java:34) ~[org.eclipse.osgi-3.13.300.jar:?]
                            at org.eclipse.osgi.launch.EquinoxFactory.newFramework(EquinoxFactory.java:27) ~[org.eclipse.osgi-3.13.300.jar:?]
                            at com.guidewire.pl.system.service.osgi.OSGiServiceManager.start(OSGiServiceManager.java:102) ~[pl-10.100.0.jar:?]
                            at com.guidewire.pl.system.server.InitTab.startDependency(InitTab.java:465) - (com.guidewire.pl.system.service.osgi.OSGiServiceManager@700654d0) ~[pl-10.100.0.jar:?]
                            at com.guidewire.pl.system.server.InitTab.enterQuiesce(InitTab.java:723) ~[pl-10.100.0.jar:?]
                            at com.guidewire.pl.system.server.InitTab.increaseRunLevelTo(InitTab.java:648) ~[pl-10.100.0.jar:?]
                        ... 47 more
```

`

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I just deleted a couple of signatures from **org.eclipse.osgi-3.13.300.jar** and everything started up! I found it by searching, then I opened the **META-INF** folder with **winrar** and deleted **ECLIPSE_.SF** and **ECLIPSE_.RSA**